# how to set path for pandas library in /apps for Python installed in /opt in linux redhat

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, pandas, redhat

I am new to Linux and Python installation, please help to install Pandas:

we have 2 versions of Python in linux redhat

Python 2.6 under `/usr/bin/python2`

Python 3.6 under `/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/bin/python3`

We have to install Pandas library without PIP in /apps/project1/pylib and make it available for python3

I have tried to download below source pandas tar file and extracted in /apps/project1/pylib 
https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b7/93/b544dd08092b457d88e10fc1e0989d9397fd32ca936fdfcbb2584178dd2b/pandas-0.25.3.tar.gz

Also set the below path as well in bash, 
but still when I try to import pandas in Python3 it still says 
`No module named pandas`

```
PYTHONPATH=/apps/project1/pylib
PYTHONHOME=/apps/project1/pylib
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the Python 2.x version won't be active for long. So build your system in Python 3.x versions.

You need to extract the .tar.gz file and then install. You can use 
`tar -xzf <filename>.tar.gz`

Since you are running the RHEL server, you can directly use following command for installation.

```
yum install python3-pandas
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes I have extracted the file using tar -xzf, but I missed the step to install. Also I do not have access to yum as I am not root. So I have installed it just by going in to the extracted folder and giving "python3 setup.py install --prefix=/apps/project1//pylib".

Comment: If you don't have root access then  you can use install and create local build by binaries.

Answer (score 0):

I missed the step to install, So I have changed PYTHONPATH to:

export PYTHONPATH=/apps/project1/pylib/lib/python3.6/site-packages

and also I have installed the package just by going in to the extracted folder and giving

"python3 setup.py install --prefix=/apps/project1/pylib".